# A problem about Java UDP communication with multi thread

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, udp

I'm studying java network programming now and i wrote a program that the client sends 30 times current time to Server and the Server will create a new thread to parse the received UDP packet and give feedback to Client if Server receives the UDP packet.

The question is, after I run my code, the Server can receive the UDP packet and create a new thread, but it seems like `DatagramSocket` and `DatagramPacket` don't pass to the thread. Thence the thread can't give a feedback to Client and Client will wait all the time after send the first UDP packet.

My code is here:

Server

```
public class MulUDPServer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DatagramSocket socket = null; 
    DatagramPacket receivedPacket; 
    final int PORT = 10010; 
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length);
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Server start!");
        while (true) {
            // receive the packet from server
            socket.receive(receivedPacket);
            // to check if Server get the packet
            System.out.println(new String(receivedPacket.getData(), 0, receivedPacket.getLength()));
            // start the thread to handle the packet we have got
            Thread thread = new Thread(new LogicThread(socket, receivedPacket));
            thread.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            // close the connection
            socket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Thread

```
public class LogicThread implements Runnable {

DatagramSocket socket = null;
DatagramPacket receivedPacket = null;

public LogicThread(DatagramSocket socket, DatagramPacket receivedPacket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.receivedPacket = receivedPacket;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        // to test if a thread have been set up
        System.out.println("a thread have been set up");
        byte[] data = receivedPacket.getData();
        int len = receivedPacket.getLength();
        // get the client IP
        InetAddress clientAddress = receivedPacket.getAddress();
        // get the client port
        int clientPort = receivedPacket.getPort();
        // print the info about received packet
        System.out.println("Client's IP：" + clientAddress.getHostAddress());
        System.out.println("Client's port：" + clientPort);
        System.out.println("The info：" + new String(data, 0, len));
        // feedback to Client
        byte[] b = "OK".getBytes();
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length, clientAddress, clientPort);
        // send
        socket.send(sendPacket);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Client

```
public class MulUDPClient {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        DatagramSocket socket = null; 
        DatagramPacket sendPacket; 
        DatagramPacket receivedPacket; 
        String serverHost = "localhost"; 
        int serverPort = 10010; 
        try {
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(serverHost);
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(b, b.length);
            System.out.println("Client ready!");
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                // get the current time
                Date d = new Date(); 
                String content = d.toString(); 
                byte[] data = content.getBytes();
                sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, serverPort);
                socket.send(sendPacket);
                System.out.println("already send time");
                Thread.sleep(10);

                // receive packet from Server
                socket.receive(receivedPacket);
                byte[] response = receivedPacket.getData();
                int len = receivedPacket.getLength();
                String s = new String(response, 0, len);
                System.out.println("the feedback from Server：" + s);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                // close the connection
                socket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the **Result** after run the Server and Client separately in two terminals:

Server

```
Server start!
Fri Nov 23 14:52:02 CST 2018
a thread have been set up
```

Client

```
Client ready!
already send time
```

From the result we can know, the Client have send a UDP packet and the Server parse it correctly and create a thread. Then the program is waiting...

It puzzle me a few days, Can anyone help me to solve it? :). Thanks!

## Edit

### Client

**CAN NOT** work

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    Thread writerWorker = new WriterWorker(socket);
    writerWorker.start();
    Thread readerWorker = new ReaderWorker(socket);
    readerWorker.start();
}
```

**CAN** work

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    Date d = new Date(); 
    String content = d.toString(); 
    byte[] data = content.getBytes();
    sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, serverPort);
    socket.send(sendPacket);
    Thread.sleep(10);
    Thread readerWorker = new ReaderWorker(socket);
    readerWorker.start();
}
```

### WriterWorker

```
public class WriterWorker extends Thread {
    DatagramSocket socket;
    String serverHost = "localhost";
    int serverPort = 10000;
    DatagramPacket sendPacket;

    public WriterWorker(DatagramSocket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(serverHost);
            Date d = new Date();
            String content = d.toString();
            byte[] data = content.getBytes();
            sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, serverPort);
            socket.send(sendPacket);
            System.out.println("already send time");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you used a debugger to determine at which line the code stops executing?

Comment: @ItFreak. I didn't use any debugger to test my code actually, but I call print function to print some information. You can see my code in Server and I print the UDP packet to check if the Server receive the packet. After some test like this, I think the code stops  executing at Thread part.

Comment: but with a debugger you can exactly find the line where to code gets stuck and maybe we get an idea of what is blocking your thread

Comment: @ItFreak. I don't know what debugger i could use, so could you recommend me one :).

Comment: I recommend to use an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ, they come with great debug features. The solution to your problem is described in Martin Franks answer, you are waiting to receive packets and thus yoir thread gets blocked

Comment: @ItFreak.Thank you! I've tried it, but there are still have some problems...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a flaw in your logic, when you do `socket.receive(receivedPacket);` this will let the worker wait until some datagramm packets does arrive...

the right way to handle asynchron communication via sockets would be the following (here an example for client side)

```
socket = new DatagramSocket();
Thread readerWorker = new ReaderWorker(socket);
readerWorker.start();

Thread writerWorker = new WriterWorker(socket);
writerWorker.start();
```

that way you would seperate reading and writing into different threads and the blocking methode `socket.receive(...)` would not stop your writing thread...

each worker would implement it's own worker loop

writer loop:

```
while(true){
    if (sendPacket!= null){
        socket.send(sendPacket);
    }
    Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

reader loop:

```
while(true){
    socket.receive(receivedPacket);
    handlePacket(receivedPacket);
}
```

## NOTE:

that code was written totally out of my mind i didn't check proper syntax

Comment: I wrote the code like you said and I met a problem. If I use two worker, the Server get nothing. But if I just use a readerworker, the Server can receive UDP packet. It's weird,I think they are same logic. I put my code in the edit part.

Comment: i hope you did the same for the server, the server needs a reader thread and a writer thread as well...

Answer (score 0):

delete the "Thread.sleep(10)" in client

Comment: it run correctly in my ide,a call to receive() for this DatagramSocket will block ,try to set the timeout socket.setSoTimeout(xx)

Comment: After set the timeout socket.setSoTimeout(xx), the Server can receive packet and the thread in Client not block. Thanks!  But the first packet the Client send is  always lost. Because it is UDP connection?